# woocommerce chance order status and update stock programmatically

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Briefly, my store is filled with items that are sold as groups. So for bookkeeping, we sell in clumps of 20 and push people to wc-on-hold as soon as they go out of stock, and then replenish the stock manually. This is time consuming and so we are trying to make this slightly more automated.

I am trying to change order status' from `wc-processing` to `wc-on-hold` for all users who purchased a specific product which has gone out of stock. I then want to update the store stock back to a stated amount after the orders for product 'X' are changed from `wc-processing` to `wc-on-hold`. I have been playing around with sql queries and have found the way to get a table of items which are out of stock. My logic is this via the creation of a cron job;

1) Query database every 10 minutes for out of stock items

2) For out of stock items, query database for orders of that product with the status wc-processing (Orders can only have 1 SKU in them - so we need not worry about changing order status' of orders with multiple item/sku)

3) Update status to wc-on-hold

4) update stock to 20 (or whatever I set)

I can get the queries for out of stock, and the orders for the items, but I am having trouble making the update table command ... anyone know how?

**Query out of Stock**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id,mt.meta_value AS sku
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (p.id = m.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta mt ON (p.id = mt.post_id)
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND m.meta_key = '_stock'
AND m.meta_value = '0
AND mt.meta_key = '_sku'
```

**Order Status and SKU**

```
SELECT order_items.order_id as ordernum, posts.post_status as status, order_item_meta.meta_value as product,mt.meta_value as sku
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items as order_items
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt ON order_item_meta.meta_value = mt.post_id
WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND posts.post_status = 'wc-processing'
AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
AND mt.meta_key ='_sku'
```

How would I go about updating the order status and then the stock based on these queries?

Comment: My feeling is ... you are going in a wrong way... Instead of writing queries try to  Find WC hooks for updating orders and stocks.... all other things will fall in places automatically.

Comment: @Alice I think I see your point... would you have a better idea on how to tackle this?